# POSTing a multidimensional array from Python

Tags: php, python, http, post

I'm trying to POST an array to a RESTful PHP API. The idea is to allow (n>0) records, each containing a remote_id, a dimension_id and a metric.

Here's my client Python:

```
    data = urllib.urlencode([
             ("remote_id", 1),
             ("dimension_id", 1),
             ("metric",metric1),
             ("remote_id", 1),
             ("dimension_id", 2),
             ("metric",metric2)
            ])
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url=url, data=data)
```

And here's my serverside PHP

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This returns, predictably:

```
Array
(
    [remote_id] => 1
    [dimension_id] => 2
    [metric] => 16
)
```

It looks to me like I'm overwriting every instance of remote_id, dimension_id and metric with the final values, which is unsurprising since they're all keyed with identical names.

What's the proper way to do this? I can see a horrible method with unique keys (1_remote_id, 1_dimension_id, 1_metric + 2_remote_id, 2_dimension_id, 2_metric) but that doesn't scale very well.

I guess I'm after something like this PHP, but in Python:

```
<?php
$observations = array();
$observations[] = [
    "remote_id" => "a1",
    "metric_id" => "foo",
    "metric" => 1
];
$observations[] = [
    "remote_id" => "a1",
    "metric_id" => "bar",
    "metric" => 2
];
?>
```

Appreciate any tips!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote me on this (I haven't done any PHP in a LOOONG time), but this may just work:

```
data = urllib.urlencode([
           ("remote_id[]", 1),
           ("dimension_id[]", 1),
           ("metric[]",metric1),
           ("remote_id[]", 1),
           ("dimension_id[]", 2),
           ("metric[]",metric2)
        ])
```

I would give it a try anyway.

Comment: I get invalid syntax if I put the []s outside of the strings (e.g "remote_id"[]). If I put them inside I get this:

Array
(
    [remote_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [dimension_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [metric] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 16
        )

)

which looks pretty good! Thanks